# SQL Server 2019 query returns all null values when trying to separate a single column into multiples columns of data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of data that uses a `/` as delimiter. I'm trying to separate the single column of data into three columns.

My query is returning the proper number of rows, but all three columns are NULL. Does anything jump off the page as obvious that I've missed?

Here is how the data is stored in the `PGroup` column:

```
Steve/Mouse/Vitamin
Matt/Cat/Soda
Shelly/Dog/Bread
```

I'm hoping to return 3 separate columns: `Name, Pet, Food`

```
DECLARE @delimiter VARCHAR(50)
SET @delimiter='/' 

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        CAST('' + REPLACE([PGroup], @delimiter, '') + '' AS XML) AS [PXML]
    FROM 
        xx123
)
SELECT
    [PXML].value('/M[1]', 'varchar(50)') As [Name],
    [PXML].value('/M[2]', 'varchar(50)') As [Pet],
    [PXML].value('/M[3]', 'varchar(50)') As [Food]
FROM 
    CTE
```

Comment: Yes, I am using Microsoft SQL Server.  I've added the tag for that.

Comment: also provide sample data and desired ouput

Comment: what's your sql server version?

Comment: My sql server version is 2019.

Comment: <M>s are missing `CAST('<M>' + REPLACE([PGroup], @delimiter ,'</M><M>') +'</M>' AS XML)`

Comment: @lptr you should make an answer of that to get more rep. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

Notable points:

- CData section protects against XML entities like ampersand and the
  like.
- XPath expressions were adjusted to use `text()` for performance
  reasons.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT INTO @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('Steve/Mouse/Vitamin'),
('Matt/Cat/Soda'),
('Shelly/Dog/Bread');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '/';

SELECT ID
    , c.value('(/root/r[1]/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') As [Name]
    , c.value('(/root/r[2]/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') As [Pet]
    , c.value('(/root/r[3]/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') As [Food]
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
        REPLACE(tokens, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
        ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+--------+-------+---------+
| ID |  Name  |  Pet  |  Food   |
+----+--------+-------+---------+
|  1 | Steve  | Mouse | Vitamin |
|  2 | Matt   | Cat   | Soda    |
|  3 | Shelly | Dog   | Bread   |
+----+--------+-------+---------+
```

Comment: @lptr, Please up-vote: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/153a9604-7025-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0

Comment: @lptr, CData section is an improvement, not a show-stopper.